# mod_rewrite: add a header if it doesn't already exist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cors

I am attempting to add CORS handling using apache and mod_rewrite. The apache instance is front-ending multiple tomcat applications using mod_jk. Some of these applications have their own logic for adding CORS headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Max-Age, etc.

For the applications that didn't take care of the CORS logic, I would like to manage it on apache using mod rewrite.

Does anyone know if its possible to add a header to an HTTP response using mod_rewrite only if the header doesn't already exist? The browser reports an error if the CORS origin header is written twice.

Comment: provide more information

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @hjpotter92. I was hoping to spare people the details of my configuration.

Comment: Aapche 2.4.7+ provides `setifempty` argument to `Header` directive. https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_headers#header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` is to rewrite url's, not to set headers. What you want to use is `mod_headers` ([documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html)).

I don't know if mod_rewrite runs before mod_headers, but I would suggest to set environment variables using `SetEnvIf` instead ([documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)).

You can do something like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/my/app/(.*)/?$" ADDHEADERS=1

Header set Access-Control-Max-Age 123456 env=ADDHEADERS
```